# Subclass of UIButton animate sublayer with titleLabel

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, subclass, uicontrol

Im making a subclass of `UIButton` to have a custom sublayer on the buttons layer.

I make this button a `System` type in storyboard and just replace class from `UIButton` my subclass in storyboard under `Identity inspector`.

I use `System` type button instead of custom to get that fade animation on titleLabel.

Now, I want to fade the sublayer aswell when the titleLabel fades.

Ive tried the `begin/continue/endTrackingWithTouch:` methods but it doesnt change when the titleLabel changes.

```
class TAButton:UIButton {
    let innerShadowLayer = CFInnerShadow() // Custom class of CAGradientLayer


    override func beginTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        innerShadowLayer.opacity = 0.5

        return super.beginTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)
}
    override func continueTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent) -> Bool {
        let con = super.continueTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)
        println(con) // I expected this to change to false when titleLabel fades but I was wrong, its always true
        return con
    }
    override func endTrackingWithTouch(touch: UITouch, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        innerShadowLayer.opacity  = 1.0
        super.endTrackingWithTouch(touch, withEvent: event)
    }


    func setup() {
        self.setBackgroundGradient(UIColor(hex: 0x4A9BCB, alpha: 0.25), color2: UIColor(hex: 0xBAE5FF, alpha: 0.25)) // Custom function Im using
        self.makeRoundSides() // Custom function Im using

        innerShadowLayer.frame = self.bounds
        innerShadowLayer.cornerRadius = self.layer.cornerRadius
        innerShadowLayer.innerShadowRadius = 10
        innerShadowLayer.innerShadowOpacity = 0.6
        innerShadowLayer.innerShadowColor = UIColor(hex: 0x69FFF7, alpha: 1.0).CGColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(innerShadowLayer)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        setup()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work for me if I override touchesBegan and touchesEnded instead.

```
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
        innerShadowLayer.opacity = 0.5
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesEnded(touches, withEvent: event)
        innerShadowLayer.opacity = 1.0
    }
```

Comment: But a UIButton has a special effect that changes the alpha of the text when you go fas enough while holding the button. This does not do that. Any tips?